# mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1524): Plugin 'unix_socket' is not loaded in Xampp Windows 10

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I get an error when using DB Mysql using Xampp, the error is displayed in phpmyadmin browser as follows:

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> Cannot connect: invalid settings.
>
> mysqli_real_connect (): (HY000 / 1524): 'unix_socket' plugin is not
>   loaded
>
> Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
>
> mysqli_real_connect (): (HY000 / 1524): 'unix_socket' plugin is not
>   loaded
>
> phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server was
>   rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and
>   password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to
>   the information provided by the administrator of the MySQL server.

My development environment:

1. Xampp 3.2.3
2. Windows 10 Pro Lite

Previously there were no problems like this, but when I was setting up a development environment using DB Sql Server this happened. I don't know what the problem is, but maybe there is software that I installed on my computer when setting up the DB Sql Server that made this happen.
Please help me. I am very beginner so please provide a step by step solution, thank you.

Comment: Does the [information here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/) help? The plugin can be disabled with a server setting.

Comment: @Paul thanks for your response. I have found a solution, I posted it in the answer to this case. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Has been resolved. I deleted the `ib_logfile1` and `ib_logfile0` files in the `/mysql/data/` folder and restart Xampp. so far grateful, but I do not know forever. good luck going forward. thanks.